# How to detect messages have unrecognized fields?

Tags: protocol-buffers

The system I am working on uses protobuf to send messages among services. We are using protobuf2 and the implementation language is C++. Here is an example:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Msg1 {
  optional string id1 = 1;
  optional string id2 = 2;
  optional string id3 = 3;
  optional string id4 = 4;
  optional string id5 = 5;
}
```

For some practical reason, some services use an older version message definition which does not have id4 and id5. It works fine since theose services only care the rest.

Now there is a use case that services need to detects whether the message has unrecognized fields. Basically when another service sends a message with id4 or id5, I need to catch that.

Since protobuf parse function ParseFromArray() does not report error, I am not sure how to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To figure out unrecognized fields you could do something along the lines of:

```
const proto2::Reflection* reflection = yourMsg.GetReflection();
reflection->GetUnknownFields(yourMsg);
```

You can read more about it [on the official docs](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.unknown_field_set/)